# How do I do an internal test for my app on Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I tried searching online but all I get is results on how to create an internal test not where to get the link afterwards.

All I'm trying to do is test whether in-app purchases work.

When I click Internal Testing on the Play Console it says the app is "Available to Internal Testers". Ok so where is the link to the app which I can send to internal testers? Or am I misunderstanding how Internal Testing works? [image]

Comment: @Michael it seems to refer to alpha/beta testing.

Comment: Look at the second answer (the one with the pictures).

Comment: Link was right under the testers tab all along :0

Comment: @Michael is it possible to do Internal Testing while the app is Pending Publication?

Answer (score 1):

You will see a link "Internal App Sharing" under the "Setup" section. In there you will find another link like this:
https://play.google.com/console/u/0/internal-app-sharing

When you click that, you can upload your apk or appbundle. After that, there will be a sharing link to share your internal testers.

Comment: Oh. I thought Internal App sharing was something different than Internal Testing since it's in a different location in the Play Console